# Aborting a jQuery getJSON XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Turns out this was an artefact of a Firebug bug. The Ajax request was cancelled, but Firebug continued reporting it as active. Details [here](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2462&q=xhr%20abort&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Test%20Summary).

---

I have long running XMLHttpRequests and I need to be able to abort them under certain circumstances.

I set up the request in a normal way:

```
ajax = $.getJSON(url + "?updates", function(data) { ...; });
```

Later on I want to abort this request, seems straightforward:

```
ajax.abort();
```

When I look in Firebug however, I see it is still running...

I console.log out the value of ajax just before I try and abort it, it confirms that its value is and XMLHttpRequest (with a readyState of 0).

Are there restrictions on how and when abort() fires on an XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 2):

> Calling abort resets the object; the  onreadystatechange event handler is removed, and  readyState is changed to 0 (uninitialized).

i do not think it cancels the request itself, it just ignores any response (manipulating the event handler)- but i didnt really try it out yet.

but it will deifnitely allow you to reuse the object - no matter if the browser still has some thread working with the old request.

Comment: Aah!. The problem is that I end up with too many http requests and the browser hangs, so I do need to terminate it...

Comment: the quote is from the Microsoft javascript docu. From this I guess it highly depends on the browser implementation what exactly is going on. most browser will probably try to finish gracefully - thus the connections might still be up for some time until finally closed - but thats just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

you may take a look at the [JSONP-Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/)
With this Plugin you have the ability to manually abort the request.
Also take a look at ["a cautionary note"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) at IBM's Technical library:

> First and foremost, there is no error handling for JSONP calls. If the dynamic script insertion works, you get called; if not, nothing happens. It just fails silently. For example, you are not able to catch a 404 error from the server. Nor can you cancel or restart the request.

Answer (score 2):

Another great article on handling this is found here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1500-Catching-Timeout-Errors-With-jQuery-Powered-AJAX.htm.

I simply converted my .getJSON request to .ajax and added the timeout/error handling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the jquery [AJAX Queue/Cache/Abort/Block Manager](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/), maybe this can help you to prevent you current situation.